# how to replace audio track of video android

Tags: android, mp4parser

This is my code for replacing audio.  After I do so however is only getting audio.  I also have an issue where some players will not play the video after the edit.Is There Any Other Way to do this?Like MediaMuxer  Thanks In advance

```
  Movie m = MovieCreator.build(new FileDataSourceViaHeapImpl(dst.toString()));
        List<Track> nuTracks  = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Track t : m.getTracks()) {
            // Re-use all tracks besides the audio track
            if (!"soun".equals(t.getHandler())) {
                nuTracks.add(t);
            }

        }
        Track nuAudio = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceViaHeapImpl("/storage/extSdCard/Xender/audio/Temp.aac"));
            nuTracks.add(nuAudio);
            m.setTracks(nuTracks);
        Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(m);
        mp4file.writeContainer(new FileOutputStream(dst.toString()).getChannel());
```